# How to update function that is passed to the Child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Suppose I have a `Dropdown` component. Initally, I placed that `Dropdown` component in a Parent component and created my `handleChange` function and everything works fine. However, I want to abstract that `Dropdown` component into its own custom Child component and now my Parent component calls that Child component.

Now I am wondering how can I pass that `handleChange` function from my Parent component to my Child component in a way where I can update that `handleChange` function to update the states in the Child component. Not sure how to proceed with this? Do I need to use `useCallBack` function? Or something else?

---

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const identifierValue = useState([]);
  ...there are more states here.

  const handleChange = (_, items) => {
    //updates different states here
  };

  return (
    <ChildComponent
      selectedItem={identifierValue}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
};

export default ParentComponent;
```

---

```
const ChildComponent = ({ identifierValue, handleIdentifierChange }) => {

  const handleChange = (_, items) => {
    //I want to update the Child component states here
  };

  return (
    <Dropdown
      selectedItem={identifierValue}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
};

export default ChildComponent;
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for, the child component is using the wrong props in your example and the child does not have any state, so nothing to update. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @EmileBergeron My question is clear. I have a function in my parent and I want to pass that function to my child and update that function in my child component.

Comment: What do you mean by "updating that function"? See, it's not clear.

Comment: @EmileBergeron It can be any update. This is very basic stuff. It is an onChange function for a dropdown so any generic update that occurs for a dropdown.

Comment: Still unclear. Where? Which data? What are you expecting as a result? etc.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Mohamed and Zak both understand my question. I am done here.

Comment: It doesn't look like they do, hence my comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that the `handleChange` event will be triggered by an action in the Dropdown component.

If you want to update states in both the child and parent components, consider the following implementation :

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const identifierValue = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (_, items) => {
    //updates different states here
  };

  return (
    <ChildComponent
      selectedItem={identifierValue}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
};
export default ParentComponent;

const ChildComponent = ({ identifierValue, handleIdentifierChange }) => {
  const handleChange = (_, items) => {
    // Update the child states
    handleIdentifierChange();
  };

  return (
    <Dropdown
      selectedItem={identifierValue}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
};
export default ChildComponent;
```

Comment: You can delete the first part of the answer. The second part is what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the Parent component, only pass `handleChange` and `identifierValue`

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const identifierValue = useState([]);
  ...there are more states here.

  const handleChange = (_, items) => {
    //updates different states here
  };

  return (
    <ChildComponent
      identifierValue={identifierValue}
      handleChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
};

export default ParentComponent;
```

In the Child component, only retrieve `handleChange` and `identifierValue`

```
const ChildComponent = ({ identifierValue, handleChange}) => {


  return (
    <Dropdown
      selectedItem={identifierValue}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
};

export default ChildComponent;
```

Comment: Yes, that I know how to pass function props to Child component. However, how do I update that passed function to the child?

Comment: You can pass the various hooks (not shown) `//updates different states here` into the child as well.  --  Or set all the various hooks in a `.props` and pass that -- Both will act the same.

Comment: yes but that is why I asked my question because i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `props.onChange()` call inside of your `handleChange` function that is defined in the ChildComponent. If you're trying to access state setters inside of the ChildComponent that are defined in the ParentComponent, you could also pass in the state setters from the parent to the child as props.